# Upgraded to EntLib6 but now Caching block is breaking everything. Can I salvage it?

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

So I upgraded a number of projects from Enterprise library 5 to 6. Everything seemed to be going fine until the first time we tested and some code that accesses the caching block started throwing exceptions:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

After lots of googling, I was able to gather the following:

- EnterpriseLibrary.Caching was removed from Enterprise Library
- EnterpriseLibraryContainer was also removed for MSEL due to the way it does dependency resolution

So in short, the problem is that the Caching block is the last version of the library and depends on something that no longer exists.

Is there anyway to salvage this other than rewriting the entire caching layer? Can I run MSEL 5.0 alongside MSEL 6.0 in order to restore that missing object? Any other ideas?

UPDATE:
The following was found in the migration guide:

> If your application uses either the Caching Application Block, the
>   Cryptography Application Block, or the Security Application Block, you
>   must provide alternative implementations of the functionality you use
>   from these blocks. For more information, see the section “Blocks
>   Removed in Version 6” below.

So I'm reading this as "Well... you're kinda screwed." So I guess my updated question is "Have any of you found a quick solution for this?"

Comment: You have to check which dependencies the Caching App Block has in ENtlib 5. Then you can download the source code and adjust it and integrate them in your solution, did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, the Caching block uses a factory for the CacheManager which was removed from EntLib 6 completely. To overcome this, I had to reimplement ICacheManager and use that instead. I swapped that out and by doing so, I was able to salvage the prod code and remove the Caching block completely.